# Preparing a string for URL parsing (Python)

Tags: python, json, csv, url

First post here, so hopefully I will supply the needed information to guide me in the right direction.

I'm new to Python, and I'm currently working on a script that very basically takes a string from one CSV-file, feeds it to an API through URL that returns some JSON which is, in turn, stored in another CSV.

The problem is that only 10% of the data fed to the API is returned as the wanted JSON. The rest returns an error and, due to the exception in my code, is stored in output.csv as "-----".

Python-version: 2.7.10

Length of input.csv: 74826 lines

Here is the code:

```
import csv
import urllib2
import json
import datetime
import re

# Sociallytic API-key - reeeaally secret :-)
api_key = 'xxxxxxx' # Not the real key

# File destinations
input_file = 'input.csv'
output_file = 'output.csv'

def prepareRequest(comment):
    # Preparing string for parsing to URL
    space = '%20'

    comment = re.sub('[^A-ZÆØÅa-zæøå0-9]+', ' ', comment)
    comment = comment.replace('\t', ' ')
    comment = comment.replace('\n', ' ')
    comment = comment.replace(' ', space)

    return comment

def getAPIFeedback(ready_comment):
    # Construct the request
    preparedRequest = urllib2.quote('"""http://api.sociallytic.dk/?key=xxxxxx&txt=' + ready_comment + '"""')

    request = urllib2.Request(preparedRequest)

    # Making the request
    json_reply = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    loaded_json = json_reply
    loaded_json = json.loads(json_reply)

    return loaded_json


def processAPIFeeback(loaded_json):
    # Preparing comment word count
    word_count = loaded_json['count_of_words']

    # Preparing comment sentiment score - SUM OF INDIVIDUAL WORD SENTIMENT SCORES
    sent_score = loaded_json['sentiment_score']

    # Preparing comment sentiment score words - SENTIMENT SCORE / SQ(COUNT OF WORDS WITH SENTIMENT SCORE)
    sent_score_words = loaded_json['sentiment_score_words']

    # Preparing brand sentiment - NEGATIVE, NEUTRAL OR POSITIVE
    brand_sentiment = loaded_json['sentiment']

    return (word_count, sent_score, sent_score_words, brand_sentiment)


def mainFunction(input_file, output_file, api_key):
    # Create new CSV file
    with open(output_file, 'wb') as file:
        w = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        w.writerow(['status_id', 'word_count', 'sent_score', 'sent_score_words', 'brand_sentiment'])

        # Counter for returning status to user
        counter = 0

        # Open and read the CSV file
        f = open(input_file, 'r')
        csv_f = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')

        # Skip status_id header
        next(csv_f, None)

        # Displayed loading text
        print 'Processing... Please wait...'

        # Getting data from CSV file
        for row in csv_f:
            # For each iteration the counter increases with 1
            counter += 1

            # Storing status_id
            id = row[0]

            # Storing comment
            comment = row[1]


            ready_comment = prepareRequest(comment)

            # Making the API-request and writing result to output.csv
            try:
                # Parsing comment to API
                loaded_json = getAPIFeedback(ready_comment)

                # Writing status_id and API feedback to CSV file
                id_feedback = (id,) + processAPIFeeback(loaded_json)

                w.writerow(id_feedback)

            except Exception:
                w.writerow('-----')

            # Output counter to user for each 100 comments processed
            if counter % 100 == 0:
                print counter, 'comments processed.'

        # Closing the CSV files
        f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainFunction(input_file, output_file, api_key)
```

Example of a request that returns an error in my script:
http://api.sociallytic.dk/?key=xxxxxxx&txt=%22Haha%20Kenneth,%20det%20er%20ellers%20et%20meget%20godt%20bud%20%E2%80%93%20det%20kunne%20ogs%C3%A5%20v%C3%A6re%20en%20kat:)%20Buddene%20er%20der%20helt%20sikkert%20mange%20af%E2%80%A6%20Jeg%20er%20dog%20ret%20sikker%20p%C3%A5,%20at%20Jylland%20er%20det%20rigtige%20svar;)%22

But when I in input the request directly into my browser, the result comes back as it is supposed to.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try `urllib2.quote("""http://api.sociallytic.dk/?key=xxxxxxx&txt=%22Haha%20Kenneth,%‌​20det%20er%20ellers%20et%20meget%20godt%20bud%20%E2%80%93%20det%20kunne%20ogs%C3%‌​A5%20v%C3%A6re%20en%20kat:)%20Buddene%20er%20der%20helt%20sikkert%20mange%20af%E2‌​%80%A6%20Jeg%20er%20dog%20ret%20sikker%20p%C3%A5,%20at%20Jylland%20er%20det%20rig‌​tige%20svar;)%22""")
` it will decode `url` and then send request.

Comment: @SIslam: Thank you! I edited my code with the proposed "quote" function, but now it is just writing pure blanks to my output.csv. And it seems as if it never makes the request to the API.

Comment: @SIslam: I have changed the code above now. Does it look like it should work? Now it is just writing pure blanks to my output.csv. And it seems as if it never makes the request to the API.